# How to cancel current release while it is in review in Google Play App Store console?

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

i uploaded a new release in google play store console and it is in review status now.
I want to cancel this because i found some errors in it.
So i want to cancel the whole release and take it out while it is under review status.

when i googled i found a solution what is not working:

```
Open Google Play Console.
Go to your project.
Go to the "Release" section of the side-bar.
Go to the "App bundle explorer"
Find the APK/Bundle and click "Delete APK/Bundle".
```

SO these steps are not working because i have no option to delete the bundle.

Please help.

Comment: You can't once it is in review. Fix the issue and roll out a new update.

Comment: yes. i uploaded a new release and they put the last release in public.